# How to say "print single-sided"?

Tags: vocabulaire, informatique

How to ask for single-sided printing in French? (I am asking a Frenchman to print a document on recto only)

Some ideas:

- *imprime d'un seul côté*
- *imprime recto seulement*

Which expressions are correct, and are there better expressions?

Answer (score 2):

Autrefois, on disait « imprimé (ou écrit) au recto seulement ». C'est encore le terme utilisé pour parler de documents anciens. On peut encore le dire, mais de nos jours on dit souvent « imprimé en recto seul » ou « imprimé recto seul », en considérant que « recto seul » est un mode d'impression. On retrouve les mêmes mots principaux, mais le complément de lieu s'est transformé en complément de moyen. C'est probablement par analogie avec « imprimé recto-verso », pour lequel la formulation par complément de lieu « imprimé au recto et au verso » est un peu lourde.

« Impression recto seulement » me semble un peu plus courant que « impression recto seul », même si je n'y vois pas de justification grammaticale. Par contre, avec un complément de lieu, c'est l'adverbe (qualifiant l'impression) d'« impression au recto seulement » qui est plus répandu que l'adjectif (qualifiant le recto) d'« impression au recto seul » ; l'adjectif *seul* dans ce genre de construction (X à Y seul) a tendance à disparaître au profit de l'adverbe.

« Imprimer d'un seul côté » est une description équivalente qui évite d'utiliser le terme technique et littéraire (mais quand même très connu) *recto*.

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que les deux traductions sont bonnes. On pourrait dire aussi:

> « **Fais une impression** recto seulement »